# Caching library for Android

Tags: android, java, caching

I'm looking for a caching library for Android.

It must:

- be memory-based
- support serialization/deserialization so it can be persisted on application shutdown
- support time-based eviction
- support creating custom eviction policies (e.g. to support update after custom events)
- have small footprint (because we are targeting Android)
- max JDK 8 (because of Android)
- well tested

Guava's `LoadingCache` does not support custom eviction policies and [does not support serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080034/persist-guava-cache-on-shutdown).

[Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) seems promising but has pretty large footprint (740KB)